# static function in template struct not using default template argument

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have this code which I wasn't able to compile and I was wondering if there's a way around it. Error is - Argument list for class template "a" is missing.

```
//not compiling one
template <typename T = int>
struct a {
    static T x;
    static T function(T number) {
        return x = number;
    }
};

template <typename T>
T a<T>::x;

int main() {
    int b = a::function(5);
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
//compiling one
template <typename T = int>
struct a {
    static T x;
    static T function(T number) {
        return x = number;
    }
};

template <typename T>
T a<T>::x;

int main() {
    int b = a<int>::function(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Why can it not use the template argument we passed on default and how can we fix that without entering the template parameter?

Comment: what is the error? Please include it in the question

Comment: the question is unclear. You are looking for a way around what? What do you want to achieve? Why is the working code not ok?

Comment: need to have it default using int, but still have an option to change it to other types by using a<type>::function(), but defaultly a<int>::function() just by passing a::function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to do without `a<>`, just `a`?

In case your class template `a` is only intended to provide utility static functions and not act as an object (with state), you could use delegation via a function template, which returns a (dummy) `a` object, followed by using the fact that an object of a given type, say `A`, can invoke non-static as well as static member functions.

```
namespace detail {

template <typename T = int>
struct AImpl {
    static T x;
    static T function(T number) {
        return x = number;
    }
};

template <typename T>
T AImpl<T>::x;

}  // namespace detail

template<typename T = int>
constexpr detail::AImpl<T> a() { return {}; }

int main() {
    const auto b_int = a().function(5);
    const auto b_char = a<char>().function('a');
    (void)b_int; (void)b_char;
}
```

---

If you in fact always wants to use deduction and never actually specify the type of the type template parameter (when other than `int`), you could exchange class template and its static data member and member function by a single function template that wraps a variable with static storage duration:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T function(T number) {
    static T x;
    return x = number;
}

int main() {
    const auto b_int = function(5);
    const auto b_char = function('a');
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b_int), const int>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b_char), const char>, "");
    (void)b_int; (void)b_char;
}
```

This would be an entirely different (and more implicit) API, however.

Answer (score 3):

The default template parameter `int` can be used without specifying it, you just need to specify that `a` is a template:

```
int b = a<>::function(5);
      // ^^
```

Comment: is there a way to do without a<>, just a?

Comment: @pesuww Not sure. Is there any particular reason you want to do this, or just curious?

Comment: I guess need to make an alias for it `using a = _a<>`

Comment: And yes I need it for my other class which is quite big so I wanted to make it in a small scale.